# Select something from a nested select

Tags: mysql, select, join

In [my database](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db), I have a table salaries which stores all past or current salaries from the employees, and a table employees which stores my employees.

I am trying to select all employees that got a promotion:

```
select first_name, last_name 
from salaries 
join employees on employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
where salaries.from_date > employees.hire_date 
  and salary > 
  (select salary from salaries 
   where salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no and from_date = employees.hire_date) 
group by salaries.emp_no 
limit 10 ;
```

It returns:

```
+------------+-----------+
| first_name | last_name |
+------------+-----------+
| Georgi     | Facello   |
| Chirstian  | Koblick   |
| Kyoichi    | Maliniak  |
| Tzvetan    | Zielinski |
| Sumant     | Peac      |
| Mary       | Sluis     |
| Patricio   | Bridgland |
| Eberhardt  | Terkki    |
| Cristinel  | Bouloucos |
| Kazuhide   | Peha      |
+------------+-----------+
10 rows in set (10.05 sec)
```

Now I am trying to select at the same time the salaries that they have when they have been hired (because it is already selected in a nested select).

Is there any way to fetch this data from `select salary from salaries where salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no and from_date = employees.hire_date` ?

I have tried something like...

```
select first_name, last_name, first_salary.salary 
from salaries join employees on employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
where salaries.from_date > employees.hire_date and salary > 
  (select salary from salaries where salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no and from_date = employees.hire_date) 
   AS FIRST_SALARY 
group by salaries.emp_no 
limit 10 ;
```

... but it cleary does not work

(We could otherwise do an UNION because the query is already very long).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use MAX and MIN on salary:

```
SELECT employees.emp_no, first_name, last_name, MAX(salary), MIN(salary)
FROM salaries 
INNER JOIN employees ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
GROUP BY employees.emp_no, first_name, last_name
HAVING MAX(salary) > MIN(salary)
```

Edit: if you want to ensure that the max salary actually came at a later date than the hire date, you could do it this way:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM 
(SELECT employees.emp_no, first_name, last_name, MAX(salary) AS mxsal
 FROM employees
 INNER JOIN salaries
 ON employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
 GROUP BY employees.emp_no, first_name, last_name) highest
INNER JOIN
(SELECT employees.emp_no, salary
 FROM employees
 INNER JOIN salaries on employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
 WHERE employees.hire_date = salaries.from_date) starting
ON highest.emp_no = starting.emp_no
WHERE highest.mxsal > starting.salary
```

So first I created a "highest" table with the max salary per employee (mxsal). Then I joined this one with a "starting" table which contains the starting salary for each employee (starting.salary). Then only selected the records where the max salary is greater than the starting one.

Comment: Thanks. I thought to it but it could select people whose salary has decreased. That's why we should also check the dates (employees.hire_date, salaries.from_date, salaries.to_date)

Comment: I see your point. Check out the edit and let me know what you think

Comment: I don't understand why, but MySQL returns a syntax error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'starting ON[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Re-frame your query and added new column in select to select initial salary of employees

```
select first_name, 
       last_name ,
       (select top 1 salary 
        from salaries where salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no 
                                    and from_date = employees.hire_date) AS InitialSalary
from salaries 
join employees on employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
                AND salaries.from_date > employees.hire_date 
                AND salary > (select salary 
                              from salaries 
                              where salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no 
                                    and from_date = employees.hire_date) 
group by salaries.emp_no 
limit 10 ;
```